# Launch Intent from ListActivity entry - Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

I have implemented a `ListActivity`, and would like to launch a different `intent` for each possible selection of the items in the list.

For example:

[image]

Clicking on About item should launch an `intent` with a new activity, and clicking on the Access Phone Gallery item should launch an `intent` opening the Phone Gallery (for selecting an image say).

I'd like to understand two things:

1. How can I determine which item was clicked, so that I can launch the correct `intent`?
2. How can I make the items in the list change style when they are selected? (say become highlighted so that the User Experience is better)

The following is the code of `MyActivity` (implementing the `ListActivity`):

```
public class MyActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener 
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    { 

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_activity);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        listEntryClass listEntries[] = new listEntryClass[]
        {
            new listEntryClass( "About", "About" ),
            new listEntryClass( "Access Phone Gallery", "Access Gallery and Choose an Image" )
        };

        listEntryArrayAdapter adapter = new listEntryArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_entry_layout, listEntries);

        View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_header_layout, null);
        TextView headerValue = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.list_header);
        headerValue.setText( this.getString(R.string.headerPrefs) );

        listView.addHeaderView(header);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener( this );

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
    {

        Log.d(TAG, "Clicked an entry");
    }

}
```

I guess there should be something like a `switch-case` on the `id` of the clicked item at some place, but have no idea of how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How can I determine which item was clicked, so that I can launch the correct intent?**

```
   @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {

       // Here position denotes which row index you clicked.
      //If you clicked first item in ListView then row index will be zero
     // and so on...

       switch (position) {
       case 0:
           //First Item/row clicked
           break;
       case 1:
           //Second Item/row clicked
           break;
       }
   }
```

**How can I make the items in the list change style when they are selected? (say become highlighted so that the User Experience is better)**

As for setting the color, you need a `StateListDrawable` . You can set this on your list using the `android:listSelector` attribute, defining the drawable in XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/item_disabled" />
  <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/item_pressed" />
  <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/item_focused" />
</selector>
```

> ListView xml will look like below.

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:dividerHeight="0dip"
      android:divider="@null" 
      android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
      android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Comment: so I should put a `switch-case` on the position value?

Comment: and the selector should go in the layout file containing the listview?

Comment: just two final remarks if you don't mind ;D: 1) If I want to access the content of the item that was selected (say the Text it contains since it is a TextView) I should use the `view` argument?and how? 2)in my ListView I was forced to use the attribute `android:id="@android:id/list"` and was not able to define my own id, why?will it change something?

Comment: If your class extends ListActivity then you have to use android:id="@android:id/list".If your class extend Activity then you can use whatever id you want like android:id="@+id/myList". and yes you will need view argument.

Comment: THks a lot again, please just help me with this last thing before accepting the answer: are there any default android drawable resources for highlighting the list entry when pressed (with buttons they become orange automatically...)? cause I don't know how to create these: `@drawable/item_pressed"` `@drawable/item_focused"` `@drawable/item_disabled"`

Comment: If you have the chance can you please help me on the question of the last comment?thks anyway ;D

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > parent, View view, int position, long id)
 {
     if (postion == 0) {
         startActivity(MyActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
     } else if (possion == 1) {
         startActivity(MyActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
     } else {
         startActivity(MyActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
     }
 }
```